I'm trying to add text to a dialog box dynamically with Javascript but its not working
const myLibrary = ['Harry Potter','The God of Small Things'];
function Book() {
  // the constructor...
  for (let book of myLibrary) {
    // Add book element to a dialog box. Create a dialog box first
    const newDialog = document.createElement('dialog');
    newDialog.classList.add = '.new-dialog';
    newDialog.textContent = book;
    document.body.appendChild(newDialog);
    console.log(book);
  }
}
Book();

Here, I'm trying to add the text directly to the dialog box. I'm assuming I will need to first add the text to a div. And then append it to a dialog box, will that work?
Thanks in advance
Basically I'm trying to create a library, where the books show up on a dialog box in javascript. I'm a beginner and learning through the odin project so please go easy on me.

Check your dev console. classList.add is a method. Additionally, when working with classLists, you don't need the . selector. newDialog.classList.add('new-dialog');

You are missing the open attribute on the dialog element. Additionally you would want to move the appendChild out of the for loop so you don't create a dialog for every book.
const myLibrary = ['Harry Potter','The God of Small Things'];

function Book() {
  // the constructor...
  // Add book element to a dialog box. Create a dialog box first
  const newDialog = document.createElement('dialog');

  newDialog.classList.add('new-dialog');
  newDialog.setAttribute('open', '')
  
  // This can be as simple as this or you can add 
  // any valid HTML 
  newDialog.innerHTML = myLibrary.join('<br />')

  document.body.appendChild(newDialog); 
}

Book();


Nice thanks Sathish
